# VBA download file from URL (using URL List in Ecxel) and save it in a new folder. Folder name comes also from a list in excel

Tags: excel, vba, download

i need help with a vba script that looks at a list of URLs and downloads a file for each URL. The file needs to be saved in new folder. The Folder names are also in the excel sheet.

[image: this is how the folder name and download URL are structed inexcel]

```
Sub downloadFile()

   Dim chromePath As String, hl As Hyperlink
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oWinHttp As Object
    Dim URL As String, FilePath As String
    
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A7").Activate

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not (fso.FolderExists("D:\SF\")) Then MkDir "D:\SF\"
        
    If Not fso.FolderExists("D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value) Then MkDir "D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value
    
    Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value))

        URL = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 

        FilePath = "D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value
        Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        oWinHttp.Open "GET", URL, False

        oWinHttp.Send
        If oWinHttp.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write oWinHttp.ResponseBody
            oStream.Save
            oStream.SaveToFile FilePath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
       End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        If (Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)) And ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
            If Not fso.FolderExists("D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value) Then MkDir "D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value
        End If
    
    Loop
   
End Sub
```

I tried differed approaches the one think that i was not able to achieve was to download the file in the right folder.

Comment: What happens with your code? Runtime error? Nothing? Wrong files downloaded? Wrong folder? Wrong filename? Only part of the files are stored? Is the sheet filled at all? Have you used the debugger and stepped thru the code to see how it works?

Comment: it does not save the file in the right folder. Also from time to time it gets a timeout after "oWinHttp.Send", witch really makes me loose my mind. File name, can and should stay the same. The download works, the Folders are been created, the only Part that is not working is saving the file to the right folder.

Comment: For the wrong folder: Set a breakpoint to the `SaveToFile`-statement and check the content of `FilePath` (our put a `Debug.Print FilePath`-statement to check if the filename is correct). For the timeout: I guess there is a way to increase the time before a timeout happens, but I am not really familiar with it: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest#methods

Comment: that is a valid point. FilePath is carring the right path. i'm checking that using debug. How do i insert the filepath in the save command, so it will save me the file in the right folder?

Comment: Is Column A folder name only, no filename ?. What is `oStream.Save` for ?

Comment: You use `MkDir "D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value` to create a folder, then `FilePath = "D:\SF\" & ActiveCell.Value`, so `FilePath` is a folder and you need a file full name. Is the file name at the end of the used URL? According to its structure, it can be extracted, or you can write it an an adiacent cell.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub downloadFile()

    Const FOLDER = "D:\SF\"
    
    Dim fso As Object, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not (fso.FolderExists(FOLDER)) Then MkDir FOLDER

    Dim oWinHttp As Object, oStream
    Dim URL As String, FilePath As String
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, ext As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        
    r = 7
    FilePath = ws.Cells(r, "A")
    Do While Len(FilePath) > 0
    
        If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

        ' check folder exists
        If Not fso.FolderExists(FOLDER & FilePath) Then
             'Debug.Print FOLDER & FilePath
             MkDir FOLDER & FilePath
        End If

        URL = ws.Cells(r, "D").Value
        oWinHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
        oWinHttp.Send
        If oWinHttp.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            With oStream
                .Open
                .Type = 1
                .Write oWinHttp.ResponseBody

                ' determine pdf or png
                .Position = 1
                If StrConv(.read(3), vbUnicode) = "PNG" Then
                    ext = ".png"
                Else
                    ext = ".pdf"
                End If
               
                .SaveToFile FOLDER & FilePath & "File " & r & ext, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
                .Close
            End With
            n = n + 1
        Else
            MsgBox URL, vbExclamation, "Status " & oWinHttp.Status
        End If

        r = r + 1
        FilePath = ws.Cells(r, "A")
       
    Loop
    MsgBox n & " files created", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: that is beautiful. Thank you for that! Can i ask some questions: Why did you change the Do While condition?  To solve the problem, i need to save the original name of the file or at least the extension. Not all files are the same type, some are PDF some PNG, and i do not now in advance what type of file i'm downloading. Do you have any ideea how to solve that?

Comment: @Lupus I always use `Len(string) > 0` to identify blank cells, just personal preference. Do you have a spare column where you can put some text for me. for example after `oWinHttp.Send` put this line `ws.Cells(r, "E") = oWinHttp.GetResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately i get a debug, that tells me that it does not find the Header.

Comment: @lupus Try `ws.Cells(r, "E") = oWinHttp.GetAllResponseHeaders`

Comment: I get a lot of information using the AllResponseHeaders, like Chach-control, Connection-Type, cookies, vary, strict, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection, Content.Securety and X-Robots but not the file name. I'll try learning about oWinHttp and differed options that can be used with it. Maybe I can find some other Command, that can help me with that. Or If you have any others ideas, i'm grateful for any help.

Comment: @lupus OK, see update. I have used the png header to identify if png or pdf.

Comment: that is so helpful, thank you. I learned a lot from your posts.